# How to know which version of Bootstrap being used when Sass port is being used?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

There is no indication about version number in bootstrap.scss

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss

[But Bootstrap developer keep version number in css version of it](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css)

I need to work on a Website made by someone else and I wants to know which version of bootstrap is being used with less efforts.

Comment: You will find the version [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/lib/bootstrap-sass/version.rb)

Comment: @anpsmn In the project this files was not added and used.

Comment: @anpsmn only https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/tree/master/assets folder was downloaded and used

Comment: How was the installation done? If it's rails check the gem file.

Comment: Rails gem was not used. Project is non rails

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you can add the following to your config.rb

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '=<version_number>'
require 'bootstrap-sass'
```

Then you'll know what version is being used because you set it!

Comment: in the project bootstrap gem is not being used

Comment: Ahh, I would highly recommend changing to it. Is there a reason why you aren't?